# Getting percantages of numbers. PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

there is dmgs array.

$dmgs array:

```
Array ( [0] => 5.1k [1] => 3.8k [2] => 12.9k [3] => 10.4k [4] => 4.1k [5] => 8.0k [6] => 7.6k [7] => 14.9k [8] => 13.6k [9] => 3.0k )
```

0,1,2,3,4 are blue team players.
others are reds.

```
$blueteamdmg = $dmgs[0] + $dmgs[1] + $dmgs[2] + $dmgs[3] + $dmgs[4] ;
$redteamdmg = $dmgs[5] + $dmgs[6] + $dmgs[7] + $dmgs[8] + $dmgs[9] ;
```

i need to compare player's dmg to their teams dmg.

**example:** blue team did 15k dmg. dmgs[1] (player 2 blue team) did 7.5k dmg.
he did 50% dmg of his teams total dmg.

i need a other array that gives every players percantage of dmg.

like this:

```
    Array ( 
[0] => 15% // blue team
[1] => 20% // blue team
[2] => 50% // blue team
[3] => 10% // blue team
[4] => 5% // blue team
[5] => 30% // red team
[6] => 12% // red team
[7] => 22% // red team
[8] => 28% // red team
[9] => 8% // red team )
```

so there will be other array named $dmgpercantages[]

but i dont know how to do this.

sorry for bad english.

```
$dmgpercantages = array(yuzde($dmgs[0]),yuzde($dmgs[1]),yuzde($dmgs[2]),yuzde($dmgs[3]),yuzde($dmgs[4]),yuzde($dmgs[5]),yuzde($dmgs[6]),yuzde($dmgs[7]),yuzde($dmgs[8]),yuzde($dmgs[9]));

        function yuzde($dmgs[$a]) { 
        if ($a <= 4) {
        $percentage = ($blueteamdmg / $dmgs[$a]) * 100;
        echo $percentage . "%";}
        else {
            $percentage = ($redteamdmg / $dmgs[$a]) * 100;
        echo $percentage . "%";
    }
     }
```

its not working

Comment: from where do you get the damage each player made and why aren't you adding there the % of the damage he made?

Comment: how you are going to distinguish which is blue team record and which one is red team record, here what you tell that will not work with the dynamic data

Comment: im getting datas from match history site. there is no percantage feature in match history site. im not stealing thats allowed. i want to make a player stat site of a online game. if number is equal or less than 4 its blue team player. thats how u understand which player is which teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code applying only for this particular case, assuming total players always 10:

```
$dmgs = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
list($blues, $red) = array_chunk($dmgs, 5);

$blue_team_dmg = array_sum($blues);
$red_team_dmg = array_sum($red);

$blue_percents = array();
$red_percents = array();

foreach ($blues as $dmg) {
  $blues_percents[] = round($dmg / $blue_team_dmg * 100, 2);
}

foreach ($red as $dmg) {
  $red_percents[] = round($dmg / $red_team_dmg * 100, 2);
}

$dmgpercantages = array_merge($blues_percents, $red_percents);
```

result:

```
array(10) {
  [0] =>
  double(6.67)
  [1] =>
  double(13.33)
  [2] =>
  double(20)
  [3] =>
  double(26.67)
  [4] =>
  double(33.33)
  [5] =>
  double(15)
  [6] =>
  double(17.5)
  [7] =>
  double(20)
  [8] =>
  double(22.5)
  [9] =>
  double(25)
}
```